# Find nodes and their connected subgraphs with Neo4j + Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.7 and Node.js to build a REST API. The data - around 70.000 nodes and 100.000 relationships - contains very many small connected subgraphs.

One API call, for example `localhost:8000/search?name=Bussum`, should return all nodes named `Bussum` and the connected component they belong to.

Illustration:

[image: Connected components]

(Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29))

I can get all the data I need with a query like this:

```
MATCH (a {name: "Bussum" })-[r*]-(b) 
UNWIND rels AS rel 
RETURN distinct startNode(rel) AS a, type(rel), endNode(rel) AS b
```

But such a query will just return *all* triples `(a)-[r]-(b)` (not grouped per  component/subgraph). Of course, I could reconstruct the graph in Node.js and find the subgraphs myself, but this does not at all feel like the best solution. Is it possible to group the returned data in an array/collection of subgraphs/components? Which Cypher queries would match my use case better? Or should I consider using the Neo4j Java API instead?

Thanks!
Bert

Comment: how "small" are the sub graphs? DO the ones in the illustration represent smallest to biggest?

Comment: Some contain one vertex, some 100, but the majority between 5 and 10.

Comment: do the nodes in each particular sub graph have a unique identifier to that sub graph?

Comment: Can "Bussum" exist more than once within a single connected component?

Comment: @DaveBennett yes, each node has an unique identifier, but this identifier is not linked to the node's subgraph.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits yes, multiple nodes can have the same name, and those nodes don't necessarily belong to the same subgraph.

Answer (score 3):

You should still have your original start point as grouping node.

```
MATCH (root {name: "Bussum" })-[rels*]-(b) 
UNWIND rels AS rel 
RETURN root, 
       collect({start: startNode(rel), 
                 type:      type(rel), 
                  end:   endNode(rel)}) as component
```

Comment: Grouping by `root` would return one collection with all the relations from all the paths. Instead, i think the grouping should be done by `rels`.

Comment: Is there a name for this operation? (finding largest subgraph containing specific node)

Comment: This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated. (Binding a variable length relationship pattern to a variable ('rels') is deprecated and will be unsupported in a future version. The recommended way is to bind the whole path to a variable, then extract the relationships: MATCH p = (...)-[...]-(...) WITH *, relationships(p) AS rels)

Answer (score 2):

```
MATCH (a {name: "Bossum"})-[*0..]-(b)
WITH DISTINCT a, collect(DISTINCT b) AS sets
RETURN DISTINCT sets
```

This query will return (possibly) many rows, where each row is a collection of nodes that make a complete subgraph such that each subgraph is as large as possible and contains at least one node named "Bossum". Each row(subgraph) is guaranteed to be unique in the result set.

*I should note, I do not know about the performance of this method.